# Header looks weird and typed.js doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

I'm a complete beginner in creating websites. My problem is that typed.js doesn't work. Second problem is that the header has rounded corners, even if I didn't say to do that.

Code for Problem 1 :

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
strings: ["HI im am cool", "HI im not cool"],
typeSpeed: 40

}

var typed = new Typed(".typing", options);
});

</script>
```

Code for Problem 2:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <header class="navbar">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p>Fresh. Designz</p>
        </div>
        </div></header>
     .navbar {
         border-radius: none;
        left: 0;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
         background: white;
         position: fixed;
             z-index: 100;
```

Comment: A good technique here is to keep removing code until you've got a minimal example that still has the problem - it's much easier to diagnose problems (and much easier for us to help you!)

Comment: We won't "ignore" parts of teh codez cuz u were lazy to rermov it... It is *your* job to give us the [mcve].

Comment: The first of these problems seems to be duplicated [in your later question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109146/why-does-typed-js-not-work-for-my-case).

Comment: Hi helloplayer1. Please don't add [solved] devices to your titles, we don't use them here. We have an acceptance system - if the answer below resolved the problem, click on the tick icon adjacent to it, so it turns green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
strings: ["HI im am cool", "HI im not cool"],
typeSpeed: 40

}

var typed = new Typed(".typing", options);


</script>
```

I think there is a syntax error in your code try using the above code. After it your typed.js will work.