# Why does Typed.js not work for my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that typed.js doesn't work.

Code :

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
    var options = {
    strings: ["HI im am cool", "HI im not cool"],
    typeSpeed: 40

    }

    var typed = new Typed(".typing", options);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: set your border to 0 and please correct the order of your css, and if you can make a jsfiddle that would be helpful.

Comment: The path to the js file might be wrong, your css should be in the <head> tag

Comment: Css should be in the Head tag? Ok but then pls tell me  how I can put the whole thing in an style.css.

Comment: Pro tip: it looks like the questions you're asking are mostly off-topic. The standards for questions on Stack Overflow are quite high, and not all questions are accepted. In this case, you've identified that the code "doesn't work", but there is no details about what you expected to happen, and what actually happened. Moreover, you've posted two things below that are not actually answers (and they will get deleted in due course).

Comment: Thus, I would advise you to read [ask] as soon as you can, in order to avoid a future question ban (which would be automatically applied by the system).

Comment: Other tips: (2) you have some "chameleon" questions in your history. These are questions that have been substantively modified, such that the new question has little to do with the old one. In general, please avoid that - if you have a new theme to ask about, ask a new question. (3) please don't use txtspk at all here - it is not very readable, and it may alienate a portion of your readership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

For anyone that doesn't see the problem, it's a syntax error because of the brackets next to the Comment.

```
var typed = new Typed(".typing", options);
}); <!-- problem is here -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just trying to give an idea how to start:

Structure:

```
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    /* add you styles or scripts here... */ /* to add style.css */
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    HTML Content 
    /* include your scripts according to priority */

  <script>
      /* custom script goes here */ 
  < script >

  </body> 
   </html>
```